# Где можно найти JSON базу со всеми странами и городами СНГ?

Tags: веб-программирование

Где можно найти JSON базу со всеми странами и городами СНГ?

Comment: надо найти просто базу, и сделать из нее что требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[КЛАДР](https://kladr-rf.ru/) - он же классификатор адресов, к нему имеется API [kladr-api](https://kladr-api.ru/) из которого при надлежащем умении и возможно количества денег выцепить нужный JSON

Например список городов с названием начинающимся на `Мо`
https://kladr-api.ru/api.php?query=%D0%9C%D0%BE&contentType=city&&limit=10